# TypeScript Generic type of a generic type

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it possible to pass in a generic type that requires another generic type? Here's what I want to do:

```
abstract class MyClass<Stream> {
  abstract doSomething1(): Stream<number> // TS error here: Stream does not take generic parameter
  abstract doSomething2(): Stream<string> // TS error here: Stream does not take generic parameter
}

// Implementations of the abstract class:
class MyObservableClass extends MyClass<Observable> {
  doSomething1() { // returns Observable<number> }
  doSomething2() { // returns Observable<string> }
}

class MyPromiseClass extends MyClass<Promise> {
  doSomething1() { // returns Promise<number> }
  doSomething2() { // returns Promise<string> }
}
```

I also tried:

```
doSomething<Stream, T>(): Stream<T>
```

But doesn't work either.

Comment: There is no syntax to allow a generic type parameter to be itself generic.

Comment: Thanks @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. Is it a TS limitation, or is it the same in other programming languages?

Comment: There are languages that support this kind of generic type parameters (Haskell I believe but I am not sure), but it's not common in mainstream languages such as C# or Java.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir C++ (which I would consider a mainstream language) has [template template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) which are what is being asked for here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering myself: it is not possible yet (Jan 2019).

The issue is being discussed here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213

Comment: You should probably accept your own answer, this helped.