# TypeScript provide (unspecified) generic type as generic argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm looking to provide a generic type as a type argument *without resolving it to a concrete type first*. Put another way, I'm looking for a way to specify a type mapping function that I can use when inheriting from a base class.

Example (incorrect) syntax which hopefully explains better than I can:

```js
abstract class RunIt<SomeMagicConverter> {
    // The return type for this function depends on the type of the
    // argument *and* on the way the implementation class was declared:
    run<T>(o: T): SomeMagicConverter<T> { // (syntax error)
        return this.handle(o); // (imagine this does something more interesting)
    }
    protected abstract handle<T>(o: T): SomeMagicConverter<T>; // (syntax error)
}

type MyMagicConverter<T> = TypeIWantToReturn<T>; // MyMagicConverter is generic
class MyRunIt extends RunIt<MyMagicConverter> { // but we don't specify T here
    // [...]
}
new MyRunIt().run(7); // call infers T is number, so returns TypeIWantToReturn<number>
new MyRunIt().run(''); // now T is string, so returns TypeIWantToReturn<string>
```

Additionally, I want to restrict this so that `SomeMagicConverter<T> extends SomeBase<T>` is guaranteed. i.e.

```js
abstract class RunIt<SomeMagicConverter extends SomeBase>
```

---

For a more concrete example of how I hope to use this, here's a basic base-class for a wrap-with-caching (not quite my actual use-case but demonstrates the need):

```js
interface Wrapped<T> {
    contains(other: T): boolean;
}

abstract class Store {
    private readonly cached = new Map<any, any>();

    protected abstract applyWrap<T>(o: T): Wrapped<T>;

    wrap<T>(o: T): Wrapped<T> { // <-- this should return something more specific
        if (!this.cached.has(o)) {
            this.cached.set(o, this.applyWrap(o));
        }
        return this.cached.get(o);
    }
}

class Foo<T> implements Wrapped<T> {
    constructor(private readonly o: T) {}
    contains(other: T): boolean { return other === this.o; }
    extraFooFunc(): void {}
}

class FooWrapper extends Store {
    constructor() { super(); }
    protected applyWrap<T>(o: T): Foo<T> { return new Foo<T>(o); }
}

new FooWrapper().wrap(4).extraFooFunc(); // syntax error because extraFooFunc is not defined on Wrapped
```

Clearly I can work around this by defining wrapping methods, but I'd like to avoid having to do that on every child class:

```js
class FooWrapper extends Store {
    // [...]
    wrap<T>(o: T): Foo<T> { return super.wrap(o) as Foo<T>; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic generic parameters are not supported yet (March 2021). See [TypeScript Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) and a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037783) for more information.

However, what you describe can be implemented using [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) and [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```ts
// Any Converter to be used with RunIt must be added to Converters
interface Converters<T> { }

// All Converters must implement this interface
interface ConverterBase<T> { length: number }

// Maps valid keys to themselves, invalid ones to `never`
type ValidKey<T, K extends keyof Converters<T>> =
    Converters<T>[K] extends ConverterBase<T> ? K : never;

// Contains all entries from Converters where the type extends ConverterBase
type ConstrainedConverters<T> = {
    [K in keyof Converters<T> as ValidKey<T, K>]: Converters<T>[K];
};

abstract class RunIt<K extends keyof ConstrainedConverters<void>> {
    run<T>(o: T): ConstrainedConverters<T>[K] {
        return this.handle(o);
    }
    protected abstract handle<T>(o: T): ConstrainedConverters<T>[K];
}

// Re-open Converters and add some Converters
interface Converters<T> { Id: T, Array: Array<T> }

class ArrayRunIt extends RunIt<'Array'> {
    protected handle<T>(o: T) { return [o]; }
}

// @ts-expect-error Type '"Id"' does not satisfy the constraint '"Array"'.(2344)
class IdRunIt extends RunIt<'Id'> {
    protected handle<T>(o: T) { return o; }
}
```

Comment: That issue is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll have to see if your proposed workaround works for me, but it's certainly an interesting approach. I wasn't aware it was possible to extend interfaces like that. It's a pity the generic parameter isn't truly constrained to `ConstrainedConverters`, making it possible to accidentally make an object which has `never` returns on some methods (with the actual bug quite far away from the error), but it does achieve the basic idea of constraining it.

Comment: @Dave I fixed the problem with the delayed errors. Instead of mapping the invalid Converters to `never`, I now mapped the corresponding keys to `never`, which removes the whole entry from `ConstrainedConverters`. This in turn causes an error immediately when providing an invalid key to `RunIt`. The updated code contains an example for that too.