# Alternatives for a generic type with generic type parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Suppose I have two types for generic functions that only differ in their return type. One has return type `T`, the other `T[]`:

```ts
type F1 = <T>(t: T) => T
type F2 = <T>(t: T) => T[]
```

I wondered how those two types could be consolidated into one generic type. The way I imagined doing that was to have that new generic type accept another generic type as a parameter (like C++'s [template template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)):

```ts
// Caution, Fantasy-TypeScript ahead!

// Accepts generic type R as parameter
// to transform return type of generic function
type F<R> = <T>(t: T) => R<T>

// define F1 and F2 in terms of F
type Id<T> = T
type F1 = F<Id>
type F2 = F<Array>
```

However, *generic generic parameters* are not supported yet (March 2021). See [TypeScript Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) and a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037783) for more information.

What would be an alternative in TypeScript?

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach would be to use [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```ts
type F<R> = <T>(t: T) => R extends void[] ? T[] : T

type F1 = F<void>   // <T>(t: T) => T
type F2 = F<void[]> // <T>(t: T) => T[]
```

A more flexible implementation can be achieved using [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```ts
type R<T> = { Id: T, Array: T[] }
type F<K extends keyof R<any>> = <T>(t: T) => R<T>[K]

type F1 = F<'Id'>    // <T>(t: T) => T
type F2 = F<'Array'> // <T>(t: T) => T[]
```

See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66615127/380229) for a more involved example of this technique.